# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 Database error

Tags: android, database, error-handling

I made a database that save some incomes. But when I try to edit it gives me this error. android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

This is my activity.

```
public class IncomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int from_Where_I_Am_Coming = 0;
    private DBhelper mydb;
    TextView payer;
    TextView amount;
    Spinner payments;
    Spinner category;
    int id_To_Update = 0;

    private Calendar calendar;
    private TextView dateView;
    private int year, month, day;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_income);

        payer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_payer);
        amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_amount);
        dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_date);

        dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_date);
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        showDate(year, month+1, day);

        payments = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.incomeNumber);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> payments_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.recurring_income, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        payments_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        payments.setAdapter(payments_adapter);

        category = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.categoryIncome);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> income_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.category_income, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        income_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        category.setAdapter(income_adapter);

        mydb = new DBhelper(this);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");
            if (Value > 0) {
                Cursor rs = mydb.getDataIncome(Value);
                id_To_Update = Value;
                rs.moveToFirst();
                String amo = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.INCOME_COLUMN_AMOUNT));
                String pyr = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.INCOME_COLUMN_PAYER));
                String dat = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.INCOME_COLUMN_DATE));
                String pym = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.INCOME_COLUMN_PAYMENTS));
                String cat = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.INCOME_COLUMN_CATEGORY));
                if (!rs.isClosed()) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
                save.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cnc);
                cancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                amount.setText(amo);
                amount.setFocusable(false);
                amount.setClickable(false);

                payer.setText(pyr);
                payer.setFocusable(false);
                payer.setClickable(false);

                dateView.setText(dat);
                dateView.setFocusable(false);
                dateView.setClickable(false);

                payments.setSelection(getIndex(payments, pym));
                payments.setFocusable(false);
                payments.setClickable(false);

                category.setSelection(getIndex(category, cat));
                category.setFocusable(false);
                category.setClickable(false);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");
            if (Value > 0) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_income, menu);
            } else {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Edit_Income:
                Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
                save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cnc);
                cancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                amount.setEnabled(true);
                amount.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                amount.setClickable(true);

                payer.setEnabled(true);
                payer.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                payer.setClickable(true);

                dateView.setEnabled(true);
                dateView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                dateView.setClickable(true);

                payments.setEnabled(true);
                payments.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                payments.setClickable(true);

                category.setEnabled(true);
                category.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                category.setClickable(true);
                return true;
            case R.id.Delete_Income:

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteIncome)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                mydb.deleteIncome(id_To_Update);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tubapps.datepickerdb.MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // User cancelled the dialog
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog d = builder.create();
                d.setTitle("Are you sure");
                d.show();

                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void run(View view) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");
            if (Value > 0) {
                if (mydb.updateIncome(id_To_Update, amount.getText().toString(), payer.getText().toString()
                        , dateView.getText().toString(), payments.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        category.getSelectedItem().toString())) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tubapps.datepickerdb.MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                if (mydb.insertIncome(amount.getText().toString(), payer.getText().toString()
                        , dateView.getText().toString(), payments.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        category.getSelectedItem().toString())) {
                } else {
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), tubapps.datepickerdb.MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setDate(View view) {
        showDialog(999);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (id == 999) {
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, year, month, day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // arg1 = year
            // arg2 = month
            // arg3 = day
            showDate(arg1, arg2+1, arg3);
        }
    };

    private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        dateView.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
                .append(month).append("/").append(year));
    }
    private int getIndex(Spinner spinner, String myString){

        int index = 0;

        for (int i=0;i<spinner.getCount();i++){
            if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals(myString)){
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }


}
```

And this is my logcat.

```
02-11 09:36:01.766    1366-1366/tubapps.datepickerdb E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tubapps.datepickerdb/tubapps.datepickerdb.IncomeActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
            at tubapps.datepickerdb.IncomeActivity.onCreate(IncomeActivity.java:74)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is line 74 of IncomeActivity.java?

Comment: String amo = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.INCOME_COLUMN_AMOUNT));

Comment: The problem is, the cursor doesn't have any data and you are trying to access it's first index which is not available hence the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Try goonerdroid's answer below. You have to check if there's data available in the cursor before trying to access it's contents.

Comment: Have you tried it and what error does it give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this to check whether the cursor is returning true

```
if (rs != null&& rs.moveToFirst()){
        String amo = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.INCOME_COLUMN_AMOUNT));
            String pyr = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.INCOME_COLUMN_PAYER));
            String dat = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.INCOME_COLUMN_DATE));
            String pym = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.INCOME_COLUMN_PAYMENTS));
            String cat = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.INCOME_COLUMN_CATEGORY));
}
```

You were trying to read from your Cursor when it was empty, hence the Exception.

Comment: try the null check for your cursor

Comment: I managed to solve the issue but the firs row in the listview is actually the second row.

Comment: OK.the int value should start with 1 and not 0.Try it and let me know

Comment: The problem is that if I add two incomes, they are saved but when I click on the first income it takes me to new income activity . And when I click on the second income it takes me to the first income inserted in the database. And if I delete the first income the second income it takes to the same new income activity.